# How to insert Json values into Azure TableStorage?

Tags: json, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

Here is my code

I am trying to insert Json values into Azure as Entity, but I always get only the first value when I get back from Azure..Is there anything I need to change in the below code?

```
    string Emulators = "['TestEmulator1','Testemulator12','Testemulator2','TestEmulator3']";

    List<string> Emulators = new List<string>();
    EmulatorIDS.Add(Emulators);
    var jsondata = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Emulators);
    Console.WriteLine(jsondata);
    var EmulatorID = new EntityProperty(jsondata);     



    //Instantiate serializer   
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int a = rnd.Next(1, 1000);  

    DynamicTableEntity actordata = new DynamicTableEntity();


    actordata.RowKey = "Test"+a.ToString();
    actordata.PartitionKey = "test@gmail.com";
    actordata.Properties["DetailsValue"] = EmulatorID;
    actordata.Properties["OtherData"] = EmulatorID;

    TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(actordata);
    table.Execute(insertOperation);
```

Comment: Can you please describe what you mean by `but I always get only the first value when I get back from Azure`? Also, what's the output of `jsondata`?

Comment: You mean `actordata` instead of `entity` here in this code: `TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(entity);`. Correct?

Comment: I get only 'TestEmulator1' instead of TestEmulator2,3 and yes you are correct edited it

Comment: Thanks! The first two lines of code is not very clear. You are creating a string by the name `Emulators` in 1st line and then creating a list of string by the same name. Also what's `EmulatorIDS`? Can you please clarify that as well. Furthermore, you're setting the property value as `EmulatorID` (that could be the reason you're only seeing single value). May I suggest that you put the actual code that you're using. Right now it is very hard to say what exactly is going on.

Comment: I convert EmulatorID's which is a list into a Json value called "jsondata" which is ==> EmulatorID (entityproperty)

Comment: Sorry about EmulatorID thing....should've read the code properly :P. Can you share the output of `jsondata`?

Comment: It's properly coming as "json" but I believe I am trying to store as entity which is causing some problems

Comment: OK. What about the two variables with the same `Emulators` name (1st two lines of code)?

Comment: That doesn't matter, it's a coding mistake..the crux of the problem is I am trying to insert jsondata as an entity and I am not successful with that

Comment: With all due respect Shan, it does matter. If I serialize the `string Emulators` value, I will get back the same value. However if I do `List<string> Emulators`, I will get a different value back (JSON representation of the list. I would request you to put the actual code that you're using. This would help us immensely to find out what is wrong with your code. Thanks.

Comment: Leave out the code..I think my question is how to store json values in Azure and I am trying to do it via TableEntity..I think you are not being helpful here as you could have written your own code and give me an example rather than taking mine..but that's not case..I will find my solution and post it as an answer here..

Comment: Simple answer to your question is that you can't really store a JSON object. Azure Tables only support following data types - string, datetime, int32, int64, boolean, guid, double and binary. To store a JSON object, you would need to serialize that as string and then store it. If you really want to store a JSON object, do take a look at Cosmos DB (DocumentDB API). HTH.

Comment: You are absolutely wrong - See here https://christosmonogios.com/2016/12/20/Store-Dot-Net-Objects-Inside-An-Azure-Table-Storage-And-Then-Retrieve-Them-Back/

Comment: I suggest you give this a try and see how the data is actually stored in Table Storage. It is stored as string. You incur the overhead of converting the data back from string when reading.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look https://www.nuget.org/packages/ObjectFlattenerRecomposer/ version 2.0 it will automatically convert your complex objects to a writable form to table storage, it supports complex types and `ICollection/IEnumerable` type properties as well. You do not need to do any up front json conversion yourself either, the api automatically handles conversions.

Answer (score -1):

If anybody is looking for answer for this..Please see [here](https://christosmonogios.com/2016/12/20/Store-Dot-Net-Objects-Inside-An-Azure-Table-Storage-And-Then-Retrieve-Them-Back/) about how to insert Json values via TableEntity instead of using JsonPayload format